# SpringDoc/Swagger behind an nginx proxy

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

We are running a service behind an `nginx` proxy so that:

`http://service-post:8080/swagger-ui.html` is routed to public address `https://host.com/services/post/swagger-ui.html`

Or to define from the other way:

When nginx receives request on `https://host.com/services/post/swagger-ui.html`, it strips the `/services/post/` prefix and passes the request to the `post` service on `/swagger-ui.html` path.

Before setting up anything (with default SpringDoc configuration) I can correctly see the swagger docs on `http://service-post:8080/swagger-ui.html`.

To set the paths for the public address on host.com, I am using:

```
springdoc.api-docs.path:        /services/post/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path:      /services/post/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl: /services/post/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

However it seems that this brakes it completely:

`/swagger-ui.html`, `/api-docs` and `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config` return `404` both for `service-post:8080/*` and `https://host.com/services/post/*`

Only thing that seems to work is https://host.com/services/post/swagger-ui/index.html which shows the petstore documentation.

**We are not using Spring Boot**, just Spring MVC of version **5.3.1**.

So how do I set up to keep the handling of the original paths (eg. `/api-docs`), but performing the lookup on the prefixed path (`/services/post/api-docs`)?

Comment: Why are you using springdoc.swagger-ui.configUrl ?

Comment: Of course I tried not using it, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I completely ignore the default redirect:

- `swagger-ui.html` -> `swagger-ui/index.html?url=/v3/api-docs

And implemented my own one:

- `docs` -> `swagger-ui/index.html?url=MY_PREFIX/v3/api-docs`

This way I don't need to change anything and everything works with default settings.

Comment: In springdoc-openapi (and swagger too maybe) you can change the url in application.properties with the property `springdoc.swagger-ui.url` so that accessing swagger-ui.html redirects you to the correct url.

Comment: I am using nginx & accessing swagger ui from http:// host/docs/swagger-ui.html where /docs is used in nginx.conf to add headers.

The problem I am facing is swagger is making a request to /v3/api-docs/swagger-config instead of /docs/v3/api-docs/swagger-config and returns 404. I tried adding springdoc.swagger-ui.url: /docs/v3/api-docs/swagger-config in properties but no luck. 
.conf
`
location /docs {
      rewrite    /docs(.*) $1 break;
      proxy_pass http://host:9090;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
`
how to fix this from nginx side?

Answer (score 2):

It's all documented here:

- https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy

If you are not using spring-boot, you can add the ForwardedHeaderFilter bean:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html

Comment: I of course read all that documentation and tried that, however that didn't seem to work in my case.

Comment: Fortunately, the source code is open and you have the ability to customize it in this case. But this doesn't seem to be definitely the right choice in terms of maintenance and scalability.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of the solutions I found worked for me, at least not first. So here's the full solution that finally clicked:

- `application.properties`

```
# === SPRINGDOC CONFIG ===
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework

springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs/json

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/api-docs/ # <==== mind the trailing slash
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

- Full nginx configuration, I tested the setup with `docker` and served my api at `/api/user`.

```
server {
    server_name host.docker.internal;

    location /api/user/ {
        client_max_body_size 128M;
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3002/;
    }

    location /api/user/api-docs/ {
        rewrite /api/user/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix /api/user/;
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3002/;
    }
}
```

- Default sub paths

  - http://localhost:3000/api-docs/json
  - http://localhost:3002/api-docs/swagger-ui/index.html
  - http://localhost:3002/api-docs/json/swagger-config
- Reverse proxied paths

  - http://localhost:4000/api/user/api-docs/json
  - http://localhost:4000/api/user/api-docs/swagger-ui/index.html
  - http://localhost:4000/api/user/api-docs/json/swagger-config

The only problem with this setup is that you cannot rely on the redirect of swagger. You have to write the full URLs just to be safe (trailing slashes included if any).

Used versions:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath />
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-javadoc</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Also note that I was testing, the route `/api-docs/swagger-ui/index.html` was not working anymore since it was caching the config. The fix is to simply navigate to `/api-docs/`