# Cannot see swagger-ui.html on the server open-api

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.x.x, gradle 6, Java 8

and I would like to use Openapi UI for documentation instead of Swagger 2

I didn't have those issues with Swagger 2

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.3')
}
```

and swagger-ui.html is available on

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

but on Kubernetes with docker container the service is available like

```
http://serverX/api-name/...
```

And open-api documentation does'nt work on

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui.html (503)
```

If I add to redirect url some additional things

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=http:http://serverX/api-name/api-docs/swagger-config/
```

the page of Open api will be available without content

finally, if I add in Explore part this

```
/api-name/api-docs
```

not only

```
/api-docs
```

it works

How to solve it?

I would like to add some parameters to get swagger-ui on

```
http://serverX/api-name/swagger-ui.html
```

Comment: It's done. I translated it.

Comment: @Gavin I have no solution at the moment

Comment: Ah.  sorry, I took "It's done. I translated it." to mean you had a solution.

Comment: I found this to be helpful when I was in a similar position:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091452/springdoc-swagger-behind-an-nginx-proxy