# Quarkus Swagger UI not working on Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, swagger, quarkus

I'am getting Resource not found when I try to reach http://SOME_URL/q/swagger-ui when running app on  Kubernetes

I have set the property

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

http://SOME_URL/q/openapi is giving me API definition

When app is deployed locally , it works fine

Any idea ?

Comment: You may have to add configure nginx to use an x-forward header, this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65091452/springdoc-swagger-behind-an-nginx-proxy