# Swagger-ui does not work with Quarkus + AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, swagger, quarkus

I have a problem similar to the one mentioned here ([Quarkus Swagger UI not working on Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316912/quarkus-swagger-ui-not-working-on-kubernetes)), if not the same.
We have some microservices implemented in Quarkus, and we are trying to configure Swagger-ui.
Locally swagger works perfectly, once deployed in AWS, swagger is not working anymore!
When we try to access it, it is returning an Error 302 and then it redirects to a reduced path (it removes the name of the micro service from the path) and ends up throwing an Error 404.
So we have configured our property:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.path=/api/swagger-ui
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
```

It is being invoked as follows:

```
https://some_url/name_of_microservice/api/swagger-ui
```

This returns a 302 and ends up redirecting to:

```
https://some_url/api/swagger-ui/
```

Which ends up launching 404.
As you can see, when redirecting it removes the name of the microservice from the path.

**Log Cloudwatch**:
22:17:33 INFO  traceId=, spanId=, sampled= [io.qu.ht.access-log] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) xxx.xx.xx.xxx - - 01/Jun/2021:22:17:33 +0000 "GET /api/swagger-ui HTTP/1.1" 302

Any suggestions would be welcome.